# Can't pass testNg command line argument from gradle build

Tags: gradle, testng, build.gradle

I have a standard build.gradle file which suppose to run testNg tests:

```
test{
  useTestNG(){
    spiListenersToSkip = "some value" - causes "option unknown" exception
    ...
    useDefaultListeners=true
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to pass a testNg runner command line argument (spiListenersToSkip) from the build file.
The problem is that gradle testNg plugin seem to be able to work only with arguments defined in it's TestNgOptions class. One thing to mention is that the list of options in the class is much shorter than actual list of available testNg CL arguments.

Would really appreciate any thoughts on how to pass command line parameter to testNg runner.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way is to path during execution

```
gradlew test -Psuite1
```

in case you want to choose one and only one of multiple suites

```
def suite1 = project.hasProperty("suite1")
def suite2 = project.hasProperty("suite2")

test {
    useTestNG() {
        dependsOn cleanTest
        useDefaultListeners = true

        if(suite1) {
            suites "src/test/resources/simpleSuite.xml"
        }

        if(suite2) {
            suites "src/test/resources/advancedSuite.xml"
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can easily choose by passing with `-P`

`gradlew test -Psuite2`

or even 2 of three

`gradlew test -Psuite2 -Psuite1`